# Problems with multiple home screen widgets android

Tags: java, android, android-widget

In android I am trying to create two home screen widgets with independent layouts and functions for one Android app.  The widgets appear correctly at first but after calling update the widgets changed from two different widgets to two identical widgets.

Initially this code will create a blue and a green widget with a counter.  This displays normally at first but when update is called they both become blue and the counts are incorrect.

I have ensured that each widget has a separate provider class
I have checked the functionality of each widget and they work fine individually

This is the main activity which updates the widgets:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.findViewById(R.id.textTXT1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppWidgetManager man = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
                int[] ids = man.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, Widget1.class));
                Intent updateIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
                updateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
                sendBroadcast(updateIntent);
            }
        });

        this.findViewById(R.id.textTXT2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppWidgetManager man = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
                int[] ids = man.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, Widget2.class));
                Intent updateIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
                updateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
                sendBroadcast(updateIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Widget1:

```
public class Widget1 extends AppWidgetProvider {
    static int count = 0;
    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        String widgetText = "" + count;
        count++;
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget1);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

Widget2:

```
public class Widget2 extends AppWidgetProvider {
    static int count = 0;
    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        String widgetText = "" + count;
        count++;
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget2);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

//separate providers